# Object instantiation and weak references

Tags: c#, instantiation, weak-references

Although I understand the concept of weak and strong references in C# and can find a lot of materials about this matter, one simple question puzzles me.

Let's have a look at this simple scenario:

```
class MyClass {}

class MyClass2 
{
    public MyClass2()
    {
        // #1
        new MyClass();
    }
}

class Program 
{
    static void MyMethod(MyClass instance) { }        

    static void Main() 
    {   
        MyClass2 instance = new MyClass2();             

        // #2   
        MyMethod(new MyClass());

        // #3
        WeakReference<MyClass> instance2 = new WeakReference<MyClass>(new MyClass());
    }
}
```

Can we say that we have instantiated our objects using ***weak reference*** at #1, #2 and #3 ? Or just at #3? What is the difference here?

Comment: What's the downvote for?

Comment: I dont think this question deserve a down vote. There are confusion in understanding, but shouldnt be downvoted.

Comment: @un-lucky This question is not really about types, the main question here is  *'do we use weak references on lines #1 #2 #3 or not'* ?

Answer (score 3):

Only on line #3, we could somewhat<sup>1</sup> justify saying "the object was instantiated using a weak reference": In line #3, the only reference pointing to the newly created instance is a weak reference (which means that the instance may become garbage-collected right after it has been instantiated).

Line #1 is not a weak reference, it is not a reference at all. Granted, if you call something right after that (such as `new MyClass().ToString()`), a reference will automatically be briefly created that will be alive while `ToString()` is running, but that reference will be a strong one, as the instance needs to stay alive while `ToString()` is being executed.

Line #2 is not a weak reference, either; the `instance` parameter of `MyMethod` is a normal strong reference that will keep the instance created on line #2 alive for as long as the parameter is in scope.

---

<sup>1</sup>: In general, it does not make much sense to say "X was instantiated using a weak reference". Objects are instantiated using a constructor. The fact that *afterwards*, only a weak reference happens to refer to the new instance is unrelated to the process of instantiation.